# Add custom text in the media library image meta area

Tags: images, filters, hooks, media-library

I want to add some custom text in this area in the media library:
[image]

Is there a filter I could hook into or how can I add content there? If not, how do we do this using Javascript?

I want the text to **ONLY** appear if the current user can edit the image (or is the uploader of the image).

Comment: Is this text static? Or is it attachment-specific (i.e., some sort of meta data)?

Comment: @tf It is just static text instructing the user how to use each field.